# minitoc: one column and no page break in a two column document

Tags: page-breaking, minitoc

So I am using the package minitoc. Things are fine.... except when it comes to the rending of minitoc. I have a two column document, so when it appears, it is shoved inside one of the two columns. The purpose of minitoc being to highlight complex chapter structure, a single column will not due. After searching the TeX exchange the best answer I found was akin to:

```
\twocolumn[{\minitoc}]
```

This does in fact solve the two column issue. minitoc is printed in one glorious column... but with a page break.

So how can we suppress this page break?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with the help of cuted package

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\dominitoc

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}
\begin{strip}
\minitoc
\end{strip}
\section{foo1}
\section{foo2}
\section{foo3}
\section{foo4}
\section{foo5}
\section{foo6}

\end{document}
```

**Update** to adjust  vertical space one can  use `\mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{before}{\vspace{-Length}}`

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\dominitoc
\mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{before}{\vspace{-2cm}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}
\begin{strip}
\minitoc
\end{strip}
\section{foo1}
\section{foo2}
\section{foo3}
\section{foo4}
\section{foo5}
\section{foo6}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that solves it! Any idea how to elegantly reduce the spacing between chapter and minitoc (besides space)

Comment: @SumNeuron answer updated.

Comment: @SumNeuron you're welcome.